# Keras model - Unet Image Segmentation

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, keras-layer

I am attempting to recreate a UNet using the Keras model API, I have collected images of cells, and the segmented version of it and I am attempting to train a model with it. In doing so I could upload a different cell and get the segmented version of the image as a prediction.

https://github.com/JamilGafur/Unet

```
from __future__ import print_function

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from keras import losses
import os
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, concatenate, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import cv2
import numpy as np
# training data 
image_location = "C:/Users/JamilG-Lenovo/Desktop/train/"
image = image_location+"image"
label = image_location +"label"


class train_data():

    def __init__(self, image, label):
        self.image = []
        self.label = []
        for file in os.listdir(image):
            if file.endswith(".tif"):
                self.image.append(cv2.imread(image+"/"+file,0))

        for file in os.listdir(label):
            if file.endswith(".tif"):
                #print(label+"/"+file)
                self.label.append(cv2.imread(label+"/"+file,0))

    def get_image(self):
        return np.array(self.image)

    def get_label(self):
        return np.array(self.label)



def get_unet(rows, cols):
    inputs = Input((rows, cols, 1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6), conv3], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    up8 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    up9 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss = losses.mean_squared_error)

    return model



def main():
    # load all the training images
    train_set = train_data(image, label)
    # get the training image
    train_images = train_set.get_image()
    # get the segmented image
    train_label = train_set.get_label()
    print("type of train_images" + str(type(train_images[0])))
    print("type of train_label" + str(type(train_label[0])))
    print('\n')
    print("shape of train_images" + str(train_images[0].shape))
    print("shape of train_label" + str(train_label[0].shape))


    plt.imshow(train_images[0], interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title("actual image")
    plt.show()

    plt.imshow(train_label[0], interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title("segmented image")
    plt.show()
    # create a UNet (512,512)
    unet = get_unet(train_label[0].shape[0],
                    train_label[0].shape[1])

    # look at the summary of the unet
    unet.summary()
    #-----------errors start here-----------------

    # fit the unet with the actual image, train_images
    # and the output, train_label
    unet.fit(train_images, train_label, batch_size=16, epochs=10)

main()
```

When I am attempting to run it I expect it to be fitting over 10 epochs, but instead, it is throwing the following error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", 
line 144, in _standardize_input_data str(array.shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_5 to have shape (None, 
512, 512, 1) but got array with shape (1, 30, 512, 512)
```

If someone could tell me what I did wrong, what the code should be, or point me in the right direction, I would much appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that Keras is expecting a "channel last" while you are passing images in "channel first mode".

There are different ways to change this setting, please refer to this: https://keras.io/backend/

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your input data to the way keras is expecting: (number of images, row, col, 1)

Add the printouts of the image shapes, so it will be more clear.

I think the class is redundant here. just use functions, easier to debug.
Maybe you reed the images into a list, then when you transform it to array, you get this 1 as the zero shape.

```
image = []
label = []
for file in os.listdir(image):
    if file.endswith(".tif"):
        image.append(cv2.imread(image+"/"+file,0).reshape((row,col,1))

for file in os.listdir(label):
    if file.endswith(".tif"):
        label.append(cv2.imread(label+"/"+file,0)).reshape((row,col,1))
```

Then

```
unet.fit(images, label, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
```

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is quite old, but I will still like to give my 2 cents to it.
First of all, I would have to point out that the architecture you are referring to here is not of U-Net.

[U-Net](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) starts with a double convolutional layer with 64 filters each. In the above example, your model architecture starts with the 32 filter size. The padding is not supposed to be "same" but "valid" and few other issues such as you are not cropping the contracting layer's output before concatenating it to the expansive part.

You will need to have the input layer as below.

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(512, 512, 1))
```

And you will have to build the model in the following fashion.

```
model.build(input_shape=(None, 1, 512, 512))
```

That means you will have to orient your input in an above-mentioned way.
Your Github link is not working and I was unable to see the input size of the image as you have used the variables in place of the numbers. So this is my guess here.

If you are interested in knowing how the actual U-net model should look like you can see the below code.

```
def unet_model():
# declaring the input layer
# Input layer expects an RGB image, in the original paper the network consisted of only one channel.
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(572, 572, 3))
# first part of the U - contracting part
c0 = layers.Conv2D(64, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(inputs)
c1 = layers.Conv2D(64, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c0)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c1)

c3 = layers.Conv2D(128, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c2)
c4 = layers.Conv2D(128, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c3)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c5 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c4)

c6 = layers.Conv2D(256, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c5)
c7 = layers.Conv2D(256, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c6)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c8 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c7)

c9 = layers.Conv2D(512, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c8)
c10 = layers.Conv2D(512, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c9)  # This layer for concatenating in the expansive part
c11 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c10)

c12 = layers.Conv2D(1024, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c11)
c13 = layers.Conv2D(1024, activation='relu', kernel_size=3, padding='valid')(c12)

# We will now start the second part of the U - expansive part
t01 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=2, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(c13)
crop01 = layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(4, 4))(c10)

concat01 = layers.concatenate([t01, crop01], axis=-1)

c14 = layers.Conv2D(512, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(concat01)
c15 = layers.Conv2D(512, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c14)

t02 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=2, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(c15)
crop02 = layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(16, 16))(c7)

concat02 = layers.concatenate([t02, crop02], axis=-1)

c16 = layers.Conv2D(256, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(concat02)
c17 = layers.Conv2D(256, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c16)

t03 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=2, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(c17)
crop03 = layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(40, 40))(c4)

concat03 = layers.concatenate([t03, crop03], axis=-1)

c18 = layers.Conv2D(128, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(concat03)
c19 = layers.Conv2D(128, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c18)

t04 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=2, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(c19)
crop04 = layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(88, 88))(c1)

concat04 = layers.concatenate([t04, crop04], axis=-1)

c20 = layers.Conv2D(64, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(concat04)
c21 = layers.Conv2D(64, activation='relu', kernel_size=3)(c20)

# This is based on our dataset. The output channels are 3, think of it as each pixel will be classified
# into three classes, but I have written 4 here, as I do padding with 0, so we end up have four classes.
outputs = layers.Conv2D(4, kernel_size=1)(c21)  

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="u-netmodel")
return model
```