# How to load images and mask for unet ,with keras imagedatagenerator

Tags: python, keras

I need to load images and mask for unet model,i dont wanna use cv2 or any libaraires to load images.I wanna use easy way to load up these images.
My dataset strucuture

```
data/train
    1.png
    2.png

data/mask
    1_mask.png
```

while googling i found keras docs for images and mask code.but it need images and mask stored in array.Or any other method to load up images and mask.

and how to work if below is case.

```
/train:
      /dir_name/
                /images
                /masks
      /dir_name2/
                /images
                /masks
      /dir_name3/
                /images
                /masks
      /dir_name4/
                /images
                /masks
```

Answer (score 1):

check out:

for first type of dataset

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050113/imagedatagenerator-for-semantic-segmentation/58050474#58050474)!
using keras imagedatagenrator code and dataset structure.

for second type:
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645797/keras-model-unet-image-segmentation)